# Call functions from re.sub

Tags: python, regex, windows, function

This is a simple example:

```
import re

math='<m>3+5</m>'
print re.sub(r'<(.)>(\d+?)\+(\d+?)</\1>', int(r'\2') + int(r'\3'), math)
```

It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\2'
```

It sends `\\2`  instead of `3` and `5`.

Why?
How do I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python replace string pattern with output of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597370/python-replace-string-pattern-with-output-of-function)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to use a function with `re.sub` you need to pass a *function*, not an expression.  As documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub), your function should take the match object as an argument and returns the replacement string.  You can access the groups with the usual `.group(n)` methods and so on.  An example:

```
re.sub("(a+)(b+)", lambda match: "{0} as and {1} bs ".format(
    len(match.group(1)), len(match.group(2))
), "aaabbaabbbaaaabb")
# Output is '3 as and 2 bs 2 as and 3 bs 4 as and 2 bs '
```

Note that the function should return strings (since they will be put back into the original string).

Answer (score 7):

You need to use lambda function.

```
print re.sub(r'<(.)>(\d+?)\+(\d+?)</\1>', lambda m: str(int(m.group(2)) + int(m.group(3))), math)
```

Comment: Even though it was an example.