# Match same number of repetitions of character as repetitions of captured group

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I would like to clean some input that was logged from my keyboard with python and regex.
Especially when backspace was used to fix a mistake.

Example 1:

```
[in]:  'Helloo<BckSp> world'
[out]: 'Hello world'
```

This can be done with

```
re.sub(r'.<BckSp>', '', 'Helloo<BckSp> world')
```

Example 2:
However when I have several backspaces, I don't know how to delete exactly the same number of characters before:

```
[in]:  'Helllo<BckSp><BckSp>o world'
[out]: 'Hello world'
```

(Here I want to remove 'l' and 'o' before the two backspaces).

I could simply use `re.sub(r'[^>]<BckSp>', '', line)` several times until there is no `<BckSp>` left but I would like to find a more elegant / faster solution.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: I think you cannot count with regex and just looping through your regex as suggested is the best way

Comment: Is using regex a requirement (i.e. you're learning regex) or just your proposed solution?

Comment: Yes I try to use regex to learn because I am not familiar with it yet.

Comment: Please keep in mind then that, although there's likely some regex only solution without a loop, regex are not a first choice and in this case you'd be much better off with a simpler, better understandable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind and may not use regex for this case then :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Python does not support recursive regex. If you can use another language, you could try this:

```
.(?R)?<BckSp>
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/OirPNn/1

Comment: Well, one can install the PyPi regex module and use this approach in Python, too.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't very efficient but you can do that with the re module:

```
(?:[^<](?=[^<]*((?=(\1?))\2<BckSp>)))+\1
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE3pds/1)

This way you don't have to count, the pattern only uses the repetition.

```
(?: 
    [^<] # a character to remove
    (?=  # lookahead to reach the corresponding <BckSp>
        [^<]* # skip characters until the first <BckSp>
        (  # capture group 1: contains the <BckSp>s
            (?=(\1?))\2 # emulate an atomic group in place of \1?+
                        # The idea is to add the <BcKSp>s already matched in the
                        # previous repetitions if any to be sure that the following
                        # <BckSp> isn't already associated with a character
            <BckSp> # corresponding <BckSp>
        )
    )
)+ # each time the group is repeated, the capture group 1 is growing with a new <BckSp>

\1 # matches all the consecutive <BckSp> and ensures that there's no more character
   # between the last character to remove and the first <BckSp>
```

You can do the same with the regex module, but this time you don't need to emulate the possessive quantifier:

```
(?:[^<](?=[^<]*(\1?+<BckSp>)))+\1
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/XK0Wke/1)

But with the regex module, you can also use the recursion (as @Fallenhero noticed it):

```
[^<](?R)?<BckSp>
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBbS8f/1)

Comment: Can't vote for this without any explanation other than the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no support for recursion/subroutine calls, no atomic groups/possessive quantifiers in Python `re`, you may remove these chars followed with backspaces in a loop:

```
import re
s = "Helllo\b\bo world"
r = re.compile("^\b+|[^\b]\b")
while r.search(s): 
    s = r.sub("", s)
print(s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Opq22I)

The `"^\b+|[^\b]\b"` pattern will find 1+ backspace chars at the string start (with `^\b+`) and `[^\b]\b` will find all non-overlapping occurrences of any char other than a backspace followed with a backspace.

Same approach in case a backspace is expressed as some enitity/tag like a literal `<BckSp>`:

```
import re
s = "Helllo<BckSp><BckSp>o world"
r = re.compile("^(?:<BckSp>)+|.<BckSp>", flags=re.S)
while r.search(s): 
    s = r.sub("", s)
print(s)
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/SCsi6S)

Comment: The OP already considered a loop and is looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case the marker is single character you could just utilize stack which would give you the result in single pass:

```
s = "Helllo\b\bo world"
res = []

for c in s:
    if c == '\b':
        if res:
            del res[-1]
    else:
        res.append(c)

print(''.join(res)) # Hello world
```

In case the marker is literally `'<BckSp>'` or some other string with length greater than 1 you can use `replace` to substitute it to `'\b'` and use the solution above. This only works if you know that `'\b'` doesn't occur in the input. If you can't designate a substitute character you could use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and process the results:

```
s = 'Helllo<BckSp><BckSp>o world'
res = []

for part in s.split('<BckSp>'):
    if res:
        del res[-1]
    res.extend(part)

print(''.join(res)) # Hello world
```

Comment: Nice approach. Would you have a workaround if the marker is `<BckSp>` ?
Maybe replacing it with `\b` would be the simplest ...

Comment: @LouisM Replace would be the easiest option if you know a character that doesn't occur in input. I've added alternative solution for a case where you can't designate any single character to use as substitute.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly verbose but you can use this [lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944978/call-functions-from-re-sub) to count # of `<BckSp>` occurrence and use substring routines to get your final output.

```
>>> bk = '<BckSp>'

>>> s = 'Helllo<BckSp><BckSp>o world'
>>> print re.sub(r'(.*?)((?:' + bk + ')+)', lambda x: x.group(1)[0:len(x.group(1)) - len(x.group(2))/len(bk)], s)
Hello world

>>> s = 'Helloo<BckSp> world'
>>> print re.sub(r'(.*?)((?:' + bk + ')+)', lambda x: x.group(1)[0:len(x.group(1)) - len(x.group(2))/len(bk)], s)
Hello world

>>> s = 'Helloo<BckSp> worl<BckSp>d'
>>> print re.sub(r'(.*?)((?:' + bk + ')+)', lambda x: x.group(1)[0:len(x.group(1)) - len(x.group(2))/len(bk)], s)
Hello word

>>> s = 'Helllo<BckSp><BckSp>o world<BckSp><BckSp>k'
>>> print re.sub(r'(.*?)((?:' + bk + ')+)', lambda x: x.group(1)[0:len(x.group(1)) - len(x.group(2))/len(bk)], s)
Hello work
```